# Need help with the following proof about Normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Proposition: if $N$ is a subgroup of $G$ of index 2 then $N$ is normal in $G$

Proof Let $a \in G$ then $aN=N=Na$.(I understand why $aN=N$ , but I can't see why $N=Na$). If a is not in $N$ then $aN=G\setminus N$ (what does that stand for?), since $G$ has precisely two left cosets and since $G$ is the disjoint union of the two left cosets of $N$, $N$ being one of them. But similarly, if a is not in N, one sees $Na=G\setminus N$. Therefore $aN=Na$ also in this case.

Why I understand is that in this case the left cosets equals the number of right cosets. So one left and right coset is N and the other one must be aN=Na since there is no other choice.

Can you explain this proof in an easier way? thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that for all $x\in N$, $xN=n=Nx$. Now, if you take $a\in G\setminus N$, then $aN=G\setminus N=Na$. So, for all $g\in G$ we have $gN=Ng$, i.e. $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: what do you mean with $aN=G \setminus N$?

Comment: @daniel when you say that $N$ have index 2 in $G$, you are saying that $\{N,aN\}$ is a partition of $G$, for all $a\in G\setminus N$.

Comment: Ok, I hate this notation. $G \setminus N$ can mean left coset or an element that is G and not in N.

Comment: Yes. In this case, these notions coincide.